# React Bootstrap - how to center image vertically in a row

Tags: css, reactjs

My images at the moment are not centered vertically and I can't seem to fix it.

```
<Grid>
  <Row className={styles.contain}>
   <Col md={6} md={4} >
    <div className={styles.testing>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7NFV6Nnpkalk5cEU" />
    </div>
    </Col>
    <Col md={6} md={4} >
     <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7NFV6Nnpkalk5cEU" />
    </Col>
    <Col md={6} md={4} >
     <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7NFV6Nnpkalk5cEU" />
    </Col>
  </Row>
<Grid>
```

and here is the css:

```
.contain{
height:100%;

}
.testing{
     vertical-align: middle;
     display:inline-block;
}
```

This had no effect on the image.

Comment: I think you just need to apply `vertical-align` to your `<Col>`s, not just the nested `.testing` div since `vertical-align` works with siblings and `.testing` has no siblings. this work? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/KqXWdG If not can you just give us rendered html/css please? Not sure what your react code is compiling to.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the Bootstrap version. I'll assume it's Bootstrap 3 and not 4 (you would have written Reactstrap instead of Boostrap React).

Columns in B3 are floated by default and float is not vertical-align friendly as you may already know. So you could just apply `display-inline:block` to your columns and then vertical-align: middle. Doing so, you'll face the famous [4px gap](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

You could also use flexboxes, but instead of "hacking" B3, you should then just go with B4 ;)

Note1: You don't need that `<div className={styles.testing}></div>`

Note2: `<Col md={6} md={4}>` is not good. You repeat md attribute for nothing here.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `className` of a `Row` to `justify-content-x-center`

The `screen_size` can be `xs,sm,md,lg,xl`

The following example will show how to center `ONE` column in a `row`.

```
<Row className="justify-content-md-center row">
    <Col className="col" screen_size={6}>
      <img src = '...'/>
    </Col>
</Row

.row {
  border: 1px solid black
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

Added extra CSS in the example so you can see the `row` and `col` in your browser for visual understanding.

If you wish to center more images within that `SAME` column, all you would need to do is add the images within that column.

Ex.

```
<Row className="justify-content-md-center row">
    <Col className="col" screen_size={6}>
      <img src = '...'/>
      <img src = '...'/>
      <img src = '...'/>
    </Col>
</Row
```